# Multiline braces in KOMA-Script titlepage before `\begin{document}`

Tags: math-mode, titles, koma-script, braces

I'm using KOMA-Script to typeset a stage play. We have two identical sets of characters, one living, one dead. I want to go for a classic look and want to to group these in the list of characters using curly braces, like in this example ("Die Räuber" by Friedrich Schiller from Reclam):
[image]

The problem is that I want to use KOMA-Script's title page back side for the list of characters, specifically `\uppertitleback{}`. When try this

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % \text{}

\title{Kopenhagen}
\author{Michael Frayn}
\date{}
\uppertitleback{%
    \addsec*{Dramatis Person\ae}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \[
    \left.
    \text{%
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        Werner \textsc{Heisenberg}\\
        Niels \textsc{Bohr}\\
        \textsc{Margrethe} Bohr, \textit{seine Frau}
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \quad
    \right}
    \text{im Jenseits \textdagger}
    \]

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        Werner \textsc{Heisenberg}\\
        Niels \textsc{Bohr}\\
        \textsc{Margrethe} Bohr, \textit{seine Frau}
    \end{tabular}
    \quad
    \text{im Diesseits \(\ast\)}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I get the error message `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`
 from pdfLaTeX.

I guess one cannot use math mode before `\begin{document}` and thus not in `\uppertitleback`.
On the other hand using inline math `\(\ast\)` to make use of a centered asterisk works fine, so maybe this is not the problem?
Is this possible without too dirty hacks? What is the correct way doing this?

Comment: you have to escape the right `}`, i.e., `\right\}` (now LaTeX thinks that your `\uppertitleback` ends with the `\right}` and that the following code should be typeset immediately, which is not allowed because there is no `\begin{document}` yet).

Comment: Okay this was stupid, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Marijn already noted in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498894/multiline-braces-in-koma-script-titlepage-before-begindocument/498900#comment1260000_498894), you will have to replace `\right}` with `\right\}` in order to make your example compilable. However, this will also horizontally center your tabulars as can be seen here:

[image]

If you instead perfer left alignment, I'd recommend using the `bigdelim` package and its `\rdelim\}` command:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigdelim}

\title{Kopenhagen}
\author{Michael Frayn}
\date{}
\uppertitleback{%
    \addsec*{Dramatis Person\ae}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}    
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l l}
    Werner \textsc{Heisenberg} & \rdelim\}{3}{*}[im Jenseits \textdagger]\\
    Niels \textsc{Bohr}\\
    \textsc{Margrethe} Bohr, \textit{seine Frau} \\
    \\
    Werner \textsc{Heisenberg} & \rdelim\}{3}{*}[im Diesseits \(\ast\)]\\
    Niels \textsc{Bohr}\\
    \textsc{Margrethe} Bohr, \textit{seine Frau} \\
   \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

With this approach all curly brackets will be at the same horizontal position. If you prefer an output as in the image in your question, put each block of persons inside a new `tabular` environment instead of using one `tabular` for the whole list.